# handleLongPressGesture: set only one pin when moving mouse

Tags: ipad, mkmapview

I am using the handleLongPressGesture-function to set a pin on a MKMap. But when I am pressing long and move the move a lot of pins appears on my map.

What can I do to forbit this?

Best regards

Comment: I figured it out. I put all my code into -> if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)

Answer (score 0):

You must check status like...

```
- (void)longPressGestureDetected:(id)sender
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gesture = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = [gesture state];
    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        set a pin here.
    }
}
```